# In json sorting ,my output getting duplicate

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

**why my code create duplicate value in my list**

```
{"name":"Sheet1!A1:M26","rows":[[{"v":"Date"},{"v":"Release"},{"v":"Functional Ench"},{"v":"PDBs"},{"v":"Total Changes Deployed"},{"v":"Post HCL Exemption"},{"v":"\u0025 of Post HCL compared to total changes"},{"v":"Control Room Items"},{"v":"Control Room items fixed \u0028During hypercare week\u0029"},{"v":"\u0025 of Control Room compared to total changes"},{"v":"\u0025 fixed vs Open items \u0028During hypercare week\u0029"},{"v":"Number of Hotfixes"},{"v":"Hotfix Prod\u000ADeploy Date"}],[{"v":44625,"fv":"3\u002F5\u002F2022"},{"v":"15.1.1"},{"v":16,"fv":"16"},{"v":26,"fv":"26"},{"v":42,"fv":"42"},{"v":2,"fv":"2"},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],[{"v":44597,"fv":"2\u002F5\u002F2022"},{"v":"15.1.0"},{"v":41,"fv":"41"},{"v":5,"fv":"5"},{"v":46,"fv":"46"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{"v":6,"fv":"6"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{"v":13,"fv":"13"},{"v":50,"fv":"50"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{"v":44606,"fv":"14-Feb-22"}],[{"v":44506,"fv":"11\u002F6\u002F2021"},{"v":"15.0.0"},{"v":82,"fv":"82"},{"v":27,"fv":"27"},{"v":109,"fv":"109"},{"v":5,"fv":"5"},{"v":5,"fv":"5"},{"v":5,"fv":"5"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{},{"v":60,"fv":"60"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":44510,"fv":"11\u002F10\u002F2021"}],[{"v":44450,"fv":"9\u002F11\u002F2021"},{"v":"14.1.0"},{"v":71,"fv":"71"},{"v":15,"fv":"15"},{"v":86,"fv":"86"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{"v":9,"fv":"9"},{"v":8,"fv":"8"},{"v":10,"fv":"10"},{"v":89,"fv":"89"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":44459,"fv":"9\u002F20\u002F2021"}],[{"v":44408,"fv":"7\u002F31\u002F2021"},{"v":"14.0.2 Aurora"},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],[{"v":44352,"fv":"6\u002F5\u002F2021"},{"v":"14.0.1"},{"v":38,"fv":"38"},{"v":6,"fv":"6"},{"v":44,"fv":"44"},{"v":4,"fv":"4"},{"v":9,"fv":"9"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":2,"fv":"2"},{"v":100,"fv":"100"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":44354,"fv":"6\u002F7\u002F2021"}],[{"v":44324,"fv":"5\u002F8\u002F2021"},{"v":"14.0.0"},{"v":55,"fv":"55"},{"v":6,"fv":"6"},{"v":61,"fv":"61"},{"v":5,"fv":"5"},{"v":8,"fv":"8"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":5,"fv":"5"},{"v":33,"fv":"33"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{}],[{"v":44268,"fv":"3\u002F13\u002F2021"},{"v":"13.1.1"},{"v":20,"fv":"20"},{"v":12,"fv":"12"},{"v":32,"fv":"32"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{"v":44279,"fv":"3\u002F24\u002F2021"}],[{"v":44233,"fv":"2\u002F6\u002F2021"},{"v":"13.1.0"},{"v":30,"fv":"30"},{"v":9,"fv":"9"},{"v":39,"fv":"39"},{"v":7,"fv":"7"},{"v":18,"fv":"18"},{"v":6,"fv":"6"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{"v":"15.0.0"},{"v":50,"fv":"50"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":44239,"fv":"2\u002F12\u002F2021"}],[{"v":44212,"fv":"1\u002F16\u002F2021"},{"v":"13.0.0 \u002F 13.0.1"},{"v":54,"fv":"54"},{"v":11,"fv":"11"},{"v":65,"fv":"65"},{"v":8,"fv":"8"},{"v":15,"fv":"15"},{"v":6,"fv":"6"},{"v":4,"fv":"4"},{"v":"9.0.0"},{"v":50,"fv":"50"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":44218,"fv":"1\u002F22\u002F2021"}],[{"v":44170,"fv":"12\u002F5\u002F2020"},{"v":"12.1.2 HF"},{"v":7,"fv":"7"},{},{"v":7,"fv":"7"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":14,"fv":"14"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{"v":"14.0.0"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{}],[{"v":44107,"fv":"10\u002F3\u002F2020"},{"v":"12.1.2"},{"v":12,"fv":"12"},{"v":4,"fv":"4"},{"v":16,"fv":"16"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":6,"fv":"6"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":44127,"fv":"10\u002F23\u002F2020"}],[{"v":44078,"fv":"9\u002F4\u002F2020"},{"v":"12.1.1"},{"v":30,"fv":"30"},{"v":13,"fv":"13"},{"v":43,"fv":"43"},{"v":10,"fv":"10"},{"v":23,"fv":"23"},{"v":6,"fv":"6"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{"v":14,"fv":"14"},{"v":50,"fv":"50"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":44085,"fv":"9\u002F11\u002F2020"}],[{"v":44044,"fv":"8\u002F1\u002F2020"},{"v":"12.1.0"},{"v":39,"fv":"39"},{"v":20,"fv":"20"},{"v":59,"fv":"59"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":1.69,"fv":"1.69"},{"v":9,"fv":"9"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{"v":5.08,"fv":"5.08"},{"v":33.33,"fv":"33.33"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":44046,"fv":"8\u002F3\u002F2020"}],[{"v":43995,"fv":"6\u002F13\u002F2020"},{"v":"12.0.1"},{"v":52,"fv":"52"},{"v":69,"fv":"69"},{"v":121,"fv":"121"},{"v":7,"fv":"7"},{"v":5.79,"fv":"5.79"},{"v":5,"fv":"5"},{"v":5,"fv":"5"},{"v":0.0413,"fv":"4.13\u0025"},{"v":100,"fv":"100"},{"v":2,"fv":"2"},{"v":"16 Jun 2020\u000A19 Jun 2020"}],[{"v":43953,"fv":"5\u002F2\u002F2020"},{"v":"12.0.0"},{"v":34,"fv":"34"},{"v":33,"fv":"33"},{"v":67,"fv":"67"},{"v":10,"fv":"10"},{"v":14.96,"fv":"14.96"},{"v":7,"fv":"7"},{"v":6,"fv":"6"},{"v":8.96,"fv":"8.96"},{"v":85.71,"fv":"85.71"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{"v":"05 May 2020\u000A09 May 2020\u000A20 May 2020"}],[{"v":43925,"fv":"4\u002F4\u002F2020"},{"v":"11.1.2"},{"v":10,"fv":"10"},{"v":6,"fv":"6"},{"v":16,"fv":"16"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{"v":18.75,"fv":"18.75"},{"v":6,"fv":"6"},{"v":5,"fv":"5"},{"v":31.26,"fv":"31.26"},{"v":83.33,"fv":"83.33"},{"v":2,"fv":"2"},{"v":"09 Apr 2020\u000A15 Apr 2020"}],[{"v":43904,"fv":"3\u002F14\u002F2020"},{"v":"11.1.1"},{"v":26,"fv":"26"},{"v":11,"fv":"11"},{"v":37,"fv":"37"},{"v":8,"fv":"8"},{"v":21.62,"fv":"21.62"},{"v":12,"fv":"12"},{"v":4,"fv":"4"},{"v":10.81,"fv":"10.81"},{"v":33.33,"fv":"33.33"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":43910,"fv":"3\u002F20\u002F2020"}],[{"v":43869,"fv":"2\u002F8\u002F2020"},{"v":"11.1.0"},{"v":34,"fv":"34"},{"v":41,"fv":"41"},{"v":76,"fv":"76"},{"v":9,"fv":"9"},{"v":11.84,"fv":"11.84"},{"v":20,"fv":"20"},{"v":9,"fv":"9"},{"v":11.84,"fv":"11.84"},{"v":45,"fv":"45"},{"v":5,"fv":"5"},{"v":"11 Feb 2020\u000A12 Feb 2020\u000A18 Feb 2020\u000A21 Feb 2020\u000A06 Mar 2020"}],[{"v":43806,"fv":"12\u002F7\u002F2019"},{"v":"11.0.1"},{"v":20,"fv":"20"},{"v":15,"fv":"15"},{"v":35,"fv":"35"},{"v":2,"fv":"2"},{"v":5.71,"fv":"5.71"},{"v":4,"fv":"4"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":2.86,"fv":"2.86"},{"v":25,"fv":"25"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{}],[{"v":43778,"fv":"11\u002F9\u002F2019"},{"v":"11.0.0"},{"v":37,"fv":"37"},{"v":73,"fv":"73"},{"v":110,"fv":"110"},{"v":9,"fv":"9"},{"v":8.18,"fv":"8.18"},{"v":21,"fv":"21"},{"v":11,"fv":"11"},{"v":10,"fv":"10"},{"v":52.38,"fv":"52.38"},{"v":2,"fv":"2"},{"v":"15 Nov 2019\u000A22 Nov 2019"}],[{"v":43743,"fv":"10\u002F5\u002F2019"},{"v":"10.1.2"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":2,"fv":"2"},{"v":3,"fv":"3"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{"v":0,"fv":"0"},{}],[{"v":43715,"fv":"9\u002F7\u002F2019"},{"v":"10.1.1"},{"v":14,"fv":"14"},{"v":15,"fv":"15"},{"v":29,"fv":"29"},{"v":2,"fv":"2"},{"v":6.9,"fv":"6.9"},{"v":7,"fv":"7"},{"v":4,"fv":"4"},{"v":13.79,"fv":"13.79"},{"v":57.14,"fv":"57.14"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":"13 Sep 2019 "}],[{"v":43680,"fv":"8\u002F3\u002F2019"},{"v":"10.1.0"},{"v":35,"fv":"35"},{"v":28,"fv":"28"},{"v":63,"fv":"63"},{"v":18,"fv":"18"},{"v":28.57,"fv":"28.57"},{"v":10,"fv":"10"},{"v":6,"fv":"6"},{"v":9.52,"fv":"9.52"},{"v":60,"fv":"60"},{"v":1,"fv":"1"},{"v":"09 Aug 2019 "}],[{"v":43631,"fv":"6\u002F15\u002F2019"},{"v":"10.0.1"},{"v":15,"fv":"15"},{"v":107,"fv":"107"},{"v":112,"fv":"112"},{"v":13,"fv":"13"},{"v":10.66,"fv":"10.66"},{"v":26,"fv":"26"},{"v":23,"fv":"23"},{"v":18.85,"fv":"18.85"},{"v":88.46,"fv":"88.46"},{"v":7,"fv":"7"},{"v":"17\u002F6\u002F2019\u000A20\u002F06\u002F2019\u000A24\u002F06\u002F2019\u000A05\u002F07\u002F2019\u000A19\u002F07\u002F2019\u000A22\u002F07\u002F2019\u000A24\u002F07\u002F2019"}]]}
```

*my code are below*
here are my code, my strategy is to get the dictionary  key value pair and store in a list and out would be list with dictionary items, but it getting duplicated i dont know why

```
import json
import pprint

fp = open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\test\\asd-Copy.txt')
data = json.load(fp)

a = {}
obj =list()
for j in range(1,len(data['rows'])):
    for x in range(0,len(data['rows'][j])):
        if len(data['rows'][j][x]) == 1:
            a[data['rows'][0][x]['v']]= data['rows'][j][x]['v']
        if len(data['rows'][j][x]) == 2:
            a[data['rows'][0][x]['v']]= data['rows'][j][x]['fv']
        if len(data['rows'][j][x]) == 0:
            a[data['rows'][0][x]['v']]= data['rows'][j][x]
    pprint.pprint(a)
    
    obj.append(a)
    
pprint.pprint(obj)
```

*output should be*

```
[{'% fixed vs Open items (During hypercare week)': {},
 '% of Control Room compared to total changes': {},
 '% of Post HCL compared to total changes': {},
 'Control Room Items': {},
 'Control Room items fixed (During hypercare week)': {},
 'Date': '3/5/2022',
 'Functional Ench': '16',
 'Hotfix Prod\nDeploy Date': {},
 'Number of Hotfixes': {},
 'PDBs': '26',
 'Post HCL Exemption': '2',
 'Release': '15.1.1',
 'Total Changes Deployed': '42'}
{'% fixed vs Open items (During hypercare week)': '50',
 '% of Control Room compared to total changes': '13',
 '% of Post HCL compared to total changes': '6',
 'Control Room Items': '3',
 'Control Room items fixed (During hypercare week)': '3',
 'Date': '2/5/2022',
 'Functional Ench': '41',
 'Hotfix Prod\nDeploy Date': '14-Feb-22',
 'Number of Hotfixes': '3',
 'PDBs': '5',
 'Post HCL Exemption': '3',
 'Release': '15.1.0',
 'Total Changes Deployed': '46'}]
```

Comment: Hello, could you provide the input data?

Comment: I'm working on your code. Do you mean the output should have only two dictionaries? Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `a={}` inside the first `for` loop.

Using better naming and pythonic looping makes your code easier to reason about:

```
fp = open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\test\\asd-Copy.txt')
data = json.load(fp)
fp.close()

headers = [c['v'] for c in data["rows"][0]]

all_data = []
for row in data["rows"][1:]:
    row_data = {}
    for i, cell in enumerate(row):
        header = headers[i]
        value = None
        if len(cell) == 0:
            value = cell
        if len(cell) == 1:
            value = cell['v']
        if len(cell) == 2:
            value = cell['fv']

        row_data[header] = value

    all_data.append(row_data)

print(all_data)
```

The code can become even more readable if you extract out the logic that decides the cell value based on its length into a function:

```
def get_value(cell):
    if len(cell) == 0:
        return cell
    if len(cell) == 1:
        return cell['v']
    if len(cell) == 2:
        return cell['fv']
    return None


fp = open('data.json')
data = json.load(fp)
fp.close()

headers = [c['v'] for c in data["rows"][0]]

all_data = []
for row in data["rows"][1:]:
    row_data = {}
    for i, cell in enumerate(row):
        header = headers[i]
        row_data[header] = get_value(cell)
    all_data.append(row_data)

print(all_data)
```

Comment: You should `close` the file you open, or (better) use `with open`. It is rather unimportant here in isolation, but could lead to a pesky leak if incorporated into a bigger program.

Comment: Right. I was focused on the bug itself. Would an `fp.close()` suffice? I don't want more indentation.